# Sort a list based on a condition

Tags: ansible

I take a string as an input example:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml -i bar.ini -e flags=valuea,valueb
```

i have a dict as a var

```
sample_dict: {
  1: ["valuea"],
  2: ["valueb", "valuec"]
}
```

I want to sort `flagss.split(',')` based on the key in `sample_dict` so if my flags is passed in random order like `flags=valuec,valuea,valueb` it gets rearranged as per my `sample_dict` structure

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clear what you want. It seems this might be an interesting problem. See my answer. Is this what you want? [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Otherwise, the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question. Given the dictionary

```yaml
sample_dict:
  1: [C]
  2: [B, X]
  3: [A]
```

sort a comma-separated string according to the values of the dictionary. For example, given the string *`flags='X,C'`*, the expected result is

```yaml
result:
  - C
  - X
```

For example, the task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ result|d([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ sample_vals }}"
      when: item in _flags
      vars:
        _flags: "{{ flags.split(',') }}"
        sample_vals: "{{ sample_dict.values()|flatten }}"
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: This works thanks, I wasn't aware of flatten or what it does. Went through the docs and understood better.